# Working with static ip address in multiple devices on different network

Tags: database, networking, ip, ip-address, static-ip-address

I don't have much knowledge on networking. So I need some assist on this.

I have laptop with a static ip address connected in location A. This ip address is configured to access the database hosted on the cloud. Since it is cloud, the ip address is needed to be configured in the firewall to allow entry.
And also I have PC in location B (connected using ethernet). If I set the pc's id address to the same static ip address of the laptop, can I still connect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is - `it depends`. Most likely the IP address you put on your computer is from what is so called [private network space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). In most end user topologies nowadays, service providers provide `routers`. Those devices typically serve multiple roles. They are:

1. Provide `internetworking` between your home LAN & providers backhaul (e.g DOCSIS, xPON, xDSL, etc)
2. `WiFi` access to your house (this often the device you connect your computers to)
3. `Firewall` (in a very basic form and shape) good enough to provide basic stateful inspection and in some cases content filtering (e.g. child protection) etc.

It's very import to know how all your computers go to the internet and what Ip addresses do they use. There are to different approaches here. 1 which is widely deployed in many countries but still remains less likely is usage of IPv6. In this case, your IP address will be most likely routable down to your end station - computer, phone, tablet, etc. I suppose in your case you might be asking for IPv4. In this case (arguably) part of the firewall function of your router, is performing what is known as NAT - Network Address Translation. Imagine this

```
 10.0.0.2 [phone] -----<=> 10.0.0.1     |    
 10.0.0.3 [tablet] ---- |   router      | ------- { INTERNET }
 10.0.0.4 [computer] -- |   55.10.20.3 <=>
```

Your router will have at least two IP addresses - one, that is `internal` used as `gateway` to all your devices and another one which will be the global, public address.

In your case, it is very likely that you have address like the ones on the left (or it may as well be part of any other range from the private space defined in `RFC1918`) configured on your computer. However, when you access the cloud all your traffic will get `translated` to your public address (55.10.20.3).
The easiest way to find out what is your public address is to visit `www.whatismyip.com` which is one of the many websites on the Internet and methods available to get your `public` address. Now when it comes to your `cloud firewall` and what address you're defining there - this has to be the public one (55.10.20.3). You must bear in mind however, that this address *might* get changed over time (e.g. daily, weekly, etc) and this might get a bit tricky for you.